# Why is an Iteration Path being assigned to new Work Items

Tags: azure-devops

My workplace has a local install of Azure DevOps version 17.143.28621.4.

When I am in the `Boards > Backlog` view and click the `New Work Item` button, it opens a popup to add a new user story with a button to add the new item to the top or bottom of the queue.

When I add a new item and click `Add to Top` or `Add to Bottom`, the work item is created and is assigned the current iteration path.

Why is the current iteration's path getting added? I would like the work item to be added at the base iteration path, not in the current iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default iteration is set under `Project Settings > Boards > Team Configuration > Iterations`. By default this is set to `@CurrentIteration`, a macro which I think is self explanatory.

You can change the default iteration in the screen.

[image]

Comment: this is not working, it seems the setting used for last created item is used and default iteration setting is ignored

Comment: @marek_lani See "Note" in step 3 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#open-team-settings-list-team-iterations)

New work items added through the Work Items page or the New Work Items widget on a team dashboard don't reference the Default Iteration Path assigned to the team. Instead, new work items are assigned the last Iteration Path selected by the user. New work items added through a team's Sprints backlog or taskboard are always assigned the Iteration Path associated with the selected sprint